# Origin of 'cuz' as shortening for cousin?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations, dialects, colloquialisms, speech

Detailed answer please and thank you. I see this used a lot among youth. I'm interested to know whether it originated in the Southern US or not?

Comment: Consider that the "-in" portion of "cousin" will often be pronounced indistinctly.

Answer (score 6):

According to Green’s Dictionary of Slang the abbreviation dates back to the 16th C. so probably a BrE expression originally. Note also the Black AmE usages from the ‘60s meaning friend or as a generic term of address among males.

[cuz n.](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/cc3xw2q):

also coz, cuzz, cuzzy;

> [abbr. SE cousin, a development of mid-16C–mid-19C coz]

Comment: Thank you. What does BrE mean though?

Comment: British English

Comment: Note, that's only in print. Colloquial shortenings, especially vocatives, occur almost exclusively in speech and rarely wind up in print, even today, and when they do their spelling is far from regular. Hence, this is an account of the earliest use of the term, in this spelling, in print, that could be found. But it's far from the origin. Shortenings this simple get rediscovered and reused by each new generation, centuries before anybody thinks to write it down on parchment.

Comment: @HrgDrg The United States were not yet a separate nation from Mother England during the 1500s, so it makes little sense to speak of "BrE" or "AmE" as extant distinctions during those times now so very distant from our own. Remember too there were not even any English Colonies yet then. Jamestown in Virginia was in 1607, and the *Mayflower* didn't set sail for Plymouth until 1620. St Augustine in Florida was 1565 but it was Spanish not English, as too was San Juan, Puerto Rico back in 1521. All the earliest (lasting) European settlements in North America were Spanish not English.

Answer (score -1):

Shakespeare uses 'coz' extensively in Romeo and Juliet, around 1600. Romeo uses it most often, I think, but others use it too.  Sometimes for actual cousins, and sometimes just for buddies.

Ain't nobody never popularized words like old Will!

Comment: what a weird thing to say as if it was a general assumption he popularized the word, when just as likely he made an already popular word fashionable, thus legitimizing a written form to a possibly long standing vernacular usage.